# Facebook App Notifications at certain time

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a few facebook apps working but need one of them to create a notification for the users using it only on certain days at a certain time. How do i do this?

Example: Every Tuesday at 7:00 a.m. push notification at user's time zone. This means that it should post at 7:00 a.m. at the user's 7:00 a.m. not developers time zone this way it applies to all users at correct time. When user clicks on notification, it takes you to apps.facebook.com/myapp

(FYI, by push notifications i am referring to the user being notified via the globe icon.)

How can one get this working like this? Is there a sample code that would do this? I have read through the facebook app api but it does not mention how to post notifications at certain times so just linking to the api would probably not help much, hence this question.

Also, would we need additional permissions for the app other than the default permissions when app was first created?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any way to specifically push a Facebook notification at a specified time.  However, if you are storing information about the user internally, you can use /me?fields=timezone as an offset and every hour fire off a notification to each user with the correct offset.